# UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL always nil for a photo

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am having trouble getting the image URL for a photo that my app takes using a `UIImagePickerController`. If a video is captured, the dictionary object returned in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` contains a `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` value which points to the video file.

If i take a photo, the dictionary object does not contain a `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` value, or a `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` value.

Googling around has thrown up different things, which i have tried without success, including:

- Set allowsEditing to YES (also tried NO)
- Dismiss the modal image picker before accessing the info dictionary.
- Casting the info objectForKey for the ....`MediaURL` to an `NSURL`. Failed as it was `nil`.
- Set the mediaTypes on the image picker to include `(NSString*)` `kUTTypeImage` and `(NSString*)` `kUTTypeMovie`.

But the info dictionary never contains a URL to the image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation, `info` is:

> A dictionary containing the original image and the edited image, if an
>   image was picked; or a filesystem URL for the movie, if a movie was
>   picked. The dictionary also contains any relevant editing information.

So you don't get an URL if an image has been picked. You get the image as an UIImage.

`// Get picked image from info dictionary`

`UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

`[save the image]`

Comment: is there a way to get the path of the UIImage?

Answer (score 2):

Some extra info relating to your question:

The `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` value is set only if the image is edited. This key then hold the URL to the original image. From the documentation:

> The Assets Library URL for the original version of the picked item.
>   After the user edits a picked item—such as by cropping an image or
>   trimming a movie—the URL continues to point to the original version of
>   the picked item.